# How to create a table structure using "li" tag and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a table structure using twitter bootstrap

```
    <div class="hero-unit span8 pull-right">
       <h5><span class="label label-info">General Account Settings</span></h5>
          <ul class="nav nav-list">
             <c:forEach items="${personUI}" var="entry">
                  <li id="${entry.key}">
                    <div class="span2 pull-left">
                       <span class="label">${entry.key}</span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="span2">
                       <font size="2"><span><strong>${entry.value}</strong></span></font>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span2 pull-right">
                       <font size="2">
                          <span>
                             <a href="#" class="${entry.key}">
                             <span class="add-on">
                               <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
                             </span>Edit

                               </a>
                          </span>
                      </font>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
             </c:forEach>
          </ul>
   </div>
```

But i am trying to put a horizontal line after each li. according to twitter bootstrap it says create a li with class divider to have the line. I do it but than whole structure of the table [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display forms controls you shouldn't use list or tables.

Simply you should use < form > < fieldset > and form controls.
To align and display controls properly, Bootstrap provides css classes:  "control-group", "control-label",  "controls", "input-prepend"

To horizontal line you should use < hr >

```
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fielset>
        <div class="well">
            <legend>General Account Settings</legend>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <input id="name" type="text" /> <a href=""> 
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</span>
                    </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="divider"></hr>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <input id="email" type="text" /> <a href=""> 
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</span>
                    </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="divider"></hr>
        </div>
```

[image]

See live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/udNYq/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a grid, you should use Boostrap table styles and < table > < thead > < tbody > < th > < tr > and < td >
instead < div > < lu > and < li >

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables

```
<table>
  <caption>...</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>...</th>
      <th>...</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried first time table but somebody insisted it better to use list.

Comment: No... If you want to show a grid, you should use < table >. If you want to show a list, you should use < ul >. See Bootstrap examples: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html

Comment: Tables should be used to display tabular data e.g. football Teams and their fixtures, goals for/against etc. They shouldn't be used to display a form.

Comment: He asked clearly for "table structure".  so I 
 suggested to him to use tables, and I explained that be only used to display a grid